# how to make dropdown on open move the dropdowns that are underneath

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons and when you click on a dropdown opens.but when I click the button that is above I want the button under to move with it. if someone understands what I want to do, please help :)

in the code snippet one button cant be clicked when the other is open, don't know why that is. when I run it on google it works

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
  $('.dropdown-menu.keep-open').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  if(1) {
    $('body').attr('tabindex', '0');
  }
  else {
    alertify.confirm().set({'reverseButtons': true});
    alertify.prompt().set({'reverseButtons': true});
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    </style>
 </head>
  <body>
      <div class="data" style="width: 100vw;">
        <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%; background:#ccc">
            <button class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu keep-open" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another link</a>
                <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" /> Click here will NOT close popover</label>
                <label class="dropdown-item">empty label</label>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%; background:#ccc">
            <button class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu keep-open" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another link</a>
                <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" /> Click here will NOT close popover</label>
                <label class="dropdown-item">empty label</label>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
  
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rebuilt the dropdown to make its content in a static position instead of default absolute positioning

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'false') {
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'true')
    $($(this).data('toggle')).css('height', 'auto')
  } else if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
    $($(this).data('toggle')).css('height', 0)
  }
});
```

```css
.drpodown-content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.expanded {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="data" style="width: 100vw;">
    <div style="width: 100%; background:#ccc">
      <button class="btn btn-lg d-block w-100 dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="#dropdown1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
      <div class="bg-white drpodown-content" id="dropdown1">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another link</a>
        <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" /> Click here will NOT close popover</label>
        <label class="dropdown-item">empty label</label>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%; background:#ccc">
      <button class="btn btn-lg d-block w-100 dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="#dropdown2" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
      <div class="bg-white drpodown-content" id="dropdown2">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another link</a>
        <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" /> Click here will NOT close popover</label>
        <label class="dropdown-item">empty label</label>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```